# UITableView section header size can't vary size

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi I am trying to size the headers based on the views. However,it only resizes the first header. The others are just set to the default. I reset the size in the viewForHeaderInSection function.Here is the code for that:

```
sectionHeight[section]=descriptionView.frame.origin.y+descriptionView.frame.size.height+5;
[self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:section];

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return sectionHeight[section];
}
```

sectionHeight is a pointer to an array of floats that contains the heights and were initalized as 50.0 in viewdidload.  After checking the variables, I confirmed that the values did change, however the section header still had a height of 50 pixels.

Comment: How are you defining the sectionHeight array?

Comment: in the header file:

   float *sectionHieght;

and set in the viewdidload:

    sectionHieght=malloc(6*sizeof(float));
    sectionHieght[0]=50.0;
    sectionHieght[1]=50.0;
    sectionHieght[2]=50.0;
    sectionHieght[3]=50.0;
    sectionHieght[4]=50.0;
    sectionHieght[5]=50.0;

Comment: any reason why you didn't declare it like:  float sectionHeight[] = {50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0};  or float sectionHeight[6]; ?

Comment: because it needed to be a global variable. so I declared it in the .h

Comment: I tried declaring it the way you said, but then sectionHeight[section] became nearly zero. The way I originally declared it, the value I returned on the heightForHeaderInSection was the same as the height of the view. somehow it was changed from there.

Comment: Why not use native objective-c NSArray APIs and store NSNumbers? NSArray *sectionHeight = @[@50, @50, @50]; You have to get their float values, but it's more "typical" for iOS development than using C code... Have you tried NSLogging the results to see what is happening?

Comment: yes. I know at the heightforsection function the float values are what I want them to be that is why I am so confused.

Comment: for example I printed sectionHeight in viewForHeaderInSection and in heightforHeaderInSection and they were both the same and reasonable.

Comment: resolved. I just used the nslogs to hardcode it in